# Page wont refresh when using React Link and passing state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm just getting started with using Router, Link, and all of those things in React. In my main App.js file, I have Router tags with two Route's inside of them that look like this:

```
<Router>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Intro} />
  <Route path="/ChatRoom" component={ChatRoom} />
</Router>
```

Then, inside my Intro.js file, I am using a Link tag to go to my ChatRoom. I do so like this:

```
   <Link to={{pathname: `/ChatRoom`, state: {name: name}}}>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </Link>
```

By the way, the submit button is just a button that takes me to the next page.

It was all working perfectly fine, meaning the submit button on my Intro page was taking me to the ChatRoom. However, I then changed the pathname to have params in it, like this

```
<Link to={{pathname: `/ChatRoom?name=${name}`, state: {name: name}}}>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </Link>
```

Where the {name} is a part of the state, and I just wanted it to appear in the URL. Now, when I click on the submit button, the page is completely blank, **but if I refresh the page**, everything appears. Why is it doing that?

P.S. If I remove the state portion of the Link and just say

```
to={pathname: `/ChatRoom?name=${name}`}
```

it works completely fine. It just seems to be an error with state and the URL params combined.

Comment: Can't use `method="GET"` in the form?

Comment: Hey @Dominik, what did you mean by that? Sorry, im a beginner

Comment: Sounds like you'd like to submit your form to another page and want the values of that form to appear in the url. That's what the `GET` method does in forms. What router are you using here? React-router? If so check out the docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: @Dominik ahh yes, thank you. The thing is though that if I don't pass in state with the Link, it actually works fine the way I have written it. It only breaks when I also pass in state using Link tag along with the pathname

Comment: Indeed as you didn't specify the parameters. Check the link I sent

Comment: @Dominik i did it! Thanks so much! My only remaining question is: why do I not have to put the :(variable_name) thing if I don't have state? In other words, why is passing in state to Link causing it to break

Comment: Make sure you answer your own question here so that the next person who comes along and finds this issue sees what you learned.

Comment: I will, im just trying to get a full understanding so i can try and answer the best i can. sorry if im bad at this, it's my first post

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out the solution.

All I had to do was add the search paramater for the Link as such:

```
<Link to={{
            pathname: '/ChatRoom',
            search: `?name=${name}`,
            state: {name: name}
          }}>
```

Which separated the pathname and the query string that would come after it!